# i am trying to download an xml file from the internet, but the app shuts down everytime i try....here is my log

Tags: java, android

```
07-16 14:32:17.052: E/Trace(1193): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

07-16 14:32:17.562: I/Choreographer(1193): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

07-16 14:32:17.732: D/gralloc_goldfish(1193): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-16 14:32:20.272: D/AndroidRuntime(1193): Shutting down VM

07-16 14:32:20.272: W/dalvikvm(1193): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     ... 11 more

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at com.example.xmlparse.XML_parse.download(XML_parse.java:47)

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     ... 14 more

07-16 14:32:22.542: I/Process(1193): Sending signal. PID: 1193 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post your java code? it is difficult to tell the problem just by looking on the logcat. And also do check the line#47 of "XML_parse.java". It is throwing a null Pointer exception on that line.

Comment: can neone tell me how to add my code here? pls

Answer (score 0):

07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 14:32:20.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at com.example.xmlparse.XML_parse.download(XML_parse.java:47)

Seems ike your XML is null

Comment: http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/trialxml/options.xml, this is the link to my xml, its not null..

Comment: No it also shows this, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: also how to add my code here?? so tht i can get some useful help?

Comment: Just put down a break point on XML_parse.java:47 the XML is null. It could be due to connection problem invalid code or something else

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I think you are doing the work on your UI thread, get off of your UI thread, and do this
   on the **Non-UI thread using a Handler, or using AsyncTask**.

**2.** Pls make sure that you target XML is properly written with No-typos, as it can't reach the target, due to which its null.

Comment: File xml; 
private String down_file="options.xml";
private Context context;
URL url;
URLConnection connection;
url=new URL("http://sourceforge.net/projects/trialxml/files/options.xml");
xml=new File(context.getCacheDir(),down_file);